# Generalized Regex from a set of String

Tags: regex, string

I have this problem. I need to find automatically a way to generate a regex that match a set of string.

For example, given the set of string in input:

```
S = ["Casino Royale (1928)", "Mission Goldfinger", "A view to a kill"]
```

create iterating at the start a regex that match the first string, so:

```
regex1 = "\w{6}\s\w{6}\s\(\d{4}\)"
```

then compare regex1 with the second string, so:

```
regex2 = "\w{6-7}\s\w{6-10}(\s\(\d{4}\))?"
```

and then with the last string, so the final output is:

```
regex_output = "\w{1-7}\s\w{4-10}(\s\w{2}\s\w\s\w{4}|\s\(\d{4}\))?"
```

I would like to if it is possible to realize. Maybe it is a problem of complexity theory, maybe.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: With a set of input big enough, you'll end up with `.*`

Comment: Yes of course, but I will have max 10 String very "similar", like in the example.

Comment: Depending on your language:  `["Casino Royale (1928)", "Mission Goldfinger", "A view to a kill"].contains(input)` would be a simpler approach than a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use an alternation of literals:

```
^\QCasino Royale (1928)\E|\QMission Goldfinger\E|\QA view to a kill\E$
```

`\Q...\E` means the characters contained to be matched literally.

This approach can of course handle an arbitrarily large list of strings.